# Sending data to screen

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to use a Python program to create input and output screen for a simple GAE app.
Importing Tkinter did not work. So I am resorting to html and django but i dont have a
solid foundation in these. I simply need to enter text and have something else display
in a formatted screen based on the text. For example user enters name and code would 
display his address in a SEPARATE field (preferrably formatted in a box or something).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at,
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html

They have got good examples for putting together an easy starting app.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine is very fundamentally built around the idea of web requests; that's really the only way that you are going to be able to get data into or our of AppEngine. If you don't want to build a web application, you could use AE as the back-end for a desktop application built in Tkinter or wxPython or whatever, but then you will have two separate applications, and the desktop client will still have to use web requests to get at the server.

It's possible that AppEngine in the not the right solution to your problem. Is there some aspect of the problem that you are trying to solve that wouldn't be answered by Tkinter or wxPython with Sqllite for a database?